# HTML and Php Form not inserting or Updating the data into MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

The script I have written is used to get data from MySQL to preload the form and also edit the Form, but my script is not inserting any data, I do not know what the problem is.

It doesn't give a connection error, but no data is inserted into my DB. Any ideas?

Many Thanks in Advance.

So here is my PHP file:

```
    <?php
include 'header.php';

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "User_Name", "Password");
$db = mysql_select_db("DB_Name", $connection);
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
$Id = "1";
$AppName = $_GET['appname'];
$AppVersion = $_GET['appversion'];
$AboutTitle = $_GET['abouttitle'];
$AboutText = $_GET['abouttext'];
$Developer = $_GET['developedby'];
$Copyright = $_GET['copyright'];
$Slider1 = $_GET['slider1'];
$Slider2 = $_GET['slider2'];
$Slider3 = $_GET['slider3'];
$Slider4 = $_GET['slider4'];
$KlassenArray = $_GET['klassenarray'];
$LehrerArray = $_GET['lehrerarray'];

$query = mysql_query("update AppInfo set
AppName='$AppName', AppVersion='$AppVersion', AboutTitle='$AboutTitle',
AboutText='$AboutText', Developer='$Developer',
Copyright='$Copyright', Slider1='$Slider1', Slider2='$Slider2', Slider3='$Slider3',
Slider4='$Slider4', KlassenArray='$KlassenArray',
LehrerArray='$LehrerArray' where Id=1", $connection);
}
$query = mysql_query("select * from AppInfo", $connection);

    $update = $_GET['update'];
    $query1 = mysql_query("select * from AppInfo where Id=1", $connection);
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
        $DAppName = $row1['AppName'];
        $DAppVersion = $row1['AppVersion'];
        $DAboutTitle = $row1['AboutTitle'];
        $DAboutText = $row1['AboutText'];
        $DDeveloper = $row1['Developer'];
        $DCopyright = $row1['Copyright'];
        $DSlider1 = $row1['Slider1'];
        $DSlider2 = $row1['Slider2'];
        $DSlider3 = $row1['Slider3'];
        $DSlider4 = $row1['Slider4'];
        $DKlassenArray = $row1['KlassenArray'];
        $DLehrerArray = $row1['LehrerArray'];
    }

?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="page_title_block">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="page_title">Settings</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="row mrg-top">
                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body mrg_bottom">
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#app_settings" aria-controls="app_settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">App Settings</a></li>

                    </ul>

                    <div class="tab-content">

                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="app_settings">
                            <form action="" name="settings_from" method="get" class="form form-horizontal">
                                <div class="section">
                                    <div class="section-body">

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">App Name :-</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input type="text" name="appname" value="<?php echo $DAppName; ?>" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">App Version :-</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input type="text" name="appversion" value="<?php echo $DAppVersion; ?>" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">About Title :-</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input type="text" name="abouttitle" value="<?php echo $DAboutTitle; ?>" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">About Text :-</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input type="text" name="abouttext" value="<?php echo $DAboutText; ?>" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Developed By :-</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input type="text" name="developedby" value="<?php echo $DDeveloper; ?>" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Copyright :-</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input type="text" name="copyright" value="<?php echo $DCopyright; ?>" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Slider 1 :-</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input type="text" name="slider1" value="<?php echo $DSlider1; ?>" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Slider 2 :-</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input type="text" name="slider2" value="<?php echo $DSlider2; ?>" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Slider 3 :-</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input type="text" name="slider3" value="<?php echo $DSlider3; ?>" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Slider 4 :-</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input type="text" name="slider4" value="<?php echo $DSlider4; ?>" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Klassen Array :-</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input type="text" name="klassenarray" value="<?php echo $DKlassenArray; ?>" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Lehrer Array :-</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input type="text" name="lehrerarray" value="<?php echo $DLehrerArray; ?>" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
                                                <button type="submit" name="submit" value="update" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
    mysql_close($connection);
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: Do you have an existing row in your database with id = 1?

Comment: Yes I do, have a row with id = 1

Comment: Var dump the value of `$query` after you run your update and report back.

Comment: Actually few hours before everything was working perfect, but suddenly it stopped working and I changed nothing

Comment: Has your host changed the server over to PHP version 7 today?

Comment: you don't need to pass the connection variable in mysql_query may be that's giving problem

Comment: @vivekmodi the OP is using the old mysql_* extension (which was removed from PHP version 7).

Comment: All querries are working except update

Comment: @SpacePhoenix I don't think that the version is updated to php 7

Comment: either you have a php 7 version or remove $connection from mysql_query

Comment: You know that your code has a very serious sql injection vulnerability? By any chance do you have single quote `'` in any of the fields you are submitting?

Comment: @Jordan S I did the Var dump it is giving bool(false)

Comment: Alright. Let's figure out the error then. Add `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` after your query.

Comment: you mean like this

Comment: $query = mysql_query("update AppInfo set
AppName='$AppName', AppVersion='$AppVersion', AboutTitle='$AboutTitle',
AboutText='$AboutText', Developer='$Developer',
Copyright='$Copyright', Slider1='$Slider1', Slider2='$Slider2', Slider3='$Slider3',
Slider4='$Slider4', KlassenArray='$KlassenArray',
LehrerArray='$LehrerArray' where Id=1", $connection) or die(mysqli_error($connection));